# Python how to match a url string from html content

Tags: python

i'm trying to pull out a url from a function which is from html element

Content

```
content = 'memoizeFetch("/m/api/v3/classified/1005/221965:1jgntW:T-qH-lYVI3p2dhoiyqFPD1ehlr8/listing-profile/")'
```

My code :

```
content = 'memoizeFetch("/m/api/v3/classified/1005/221965:1jgntW:T-qH-lYVI3p2dhoiyqFPD1ehlr8/listing-profile/")'

match = re.search(r'memoizeFetch("(.*?)"', content).group(0)

print(match)
```

It doesn't work, i need to get the following string from that function:

```
 "/m/api/v3/classified/1005/221965:1jgntW:T-qH-lYVI3p2dhoiyqFPD1ehlr8/listing-profile/"
```

How i can do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the pharantesis inside the string and select group(1).

Change your code to:

```
content = 'memoizeFetch("/m/api/v3/classified/1005/221965:1jgntW:T-qH-lYVI3p2dhoiyqFPD1ehlr8/listing-profile/")'

match = re.search(r'memoizeFetch\("(.*?)"', content).group(1)

print(match)
```

Output:

```
/m/api/v3/classified/1005/221965:1jgntW:T-qH-lYVI3p2dhoiyqFPD1ehlr8/listing-profile/
```